# Are the integrated tickets for public transport in Rome valid for the FR1 train line between Fiumicino and Trastevere?

Tags: public-transport, tickets, airport-transfer, rome, fco

I'm looking at the options for public transport in Rome, and there's the *Integrated Weekly Ticket* ('Carta Integrata Settimanale', CIS), which is valid for all buses, trams, metro and Trenitalia regional trains, costing 24 EUR. I'll be arriving at Fiumicino airport, and there's a Trenitalia train (line FR1) from there to Roma Trasteverre, which is perfect for me. The train alone costs 9.50 EUR, so I'd be able to save quite a bit if I'm able to use this type of ticket.

On the [abomination of a website](http://atac.roma.it/) which belongs to ATAC, the public transport agency responsible for mass transit in Rome, it is impossible to find whether those tickets can be bought from Fiumicino airport at all, and if they are valid for this particular train.

So, in short:

- Is the weekly CIS ticket valid for use on the FR1 line?
- If yes, can I buy it from the airport?

Comment: to save - the "cheapest" airport transfer seems to be the bus.. 4 EUR.. yes, takes longer..

Comment: @yemyemyen: I'm not interested in the bus really, the train works much better for me. I was just wondering whether I could use the card which I'd purchase anyway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Rome Toolkit .com says no.](http://www.rometoolkit.com/transport/rome_travel_pass.htm)

> **What Is Not Covered By Rome Travel Passes**
>
> For buses, you can only use the Rome travel passes on the city buses.
>   You cannot use them on the Rome hop on, hop off sightseeing buses or
>   the airport buses to either of Rome's airports. On the trains the
>   entire Metro system is covered and local services in the city of Rome
>   district are also covered. **The travel passes do not cover any of the
>   trains to Fiumicino Airport,** the main airport for Rome, this includes
>   the Leonardo Express train running non-stop between Fiumicino Airport
>   and Rome's Termini Station. You cannot use the travel passes on the
>   trains to and from Rome's cruise port, Civitavecchia, which is a long
>   way outside Rome.

Some more information on this from [another discussion forum.](http://slowtalk.com/groupee/forums/a/tpc/f/862600685/m/7791061493)

> The CIS will work on the FR1 (FM1). It is the same price as the 2 zone
>   CIRS. However, the CIS may not be valid all the way to the Airport, in
>   which case you will need the regional pass, a 3-zone CIRS which is 7
>   euros more.

And.. For an 'official' confirmation

The Roma Pass website has a PDF which shows that the limit to the FR1 train is two stations before the FCO station.

> CONNECTIONS TO AND FROM AIRPORTS (Leonardo Express train, FR1 train,
>   local urban services) ARE NOT INCLUDED IN THE TWO CARDS. [Validity
>   Limit of the Roma Pass.](http://www.romapass.it/doc/zonaA_romapass.pdf)